# mysqldump command when you don't specify path outputs to terminal?

Tags: mysqldump

I'm wondering if I don't specify path to mysqldump command, no file will be saved and output will be just seen on terminal screen?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you mean

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump args
```

versus

```
mysqldump args
```

which is what "path to mysqldump command" sounds like. But that you mean

```
mysqldump args > outputfile
```

or

```
mysqldump args -r outputfile
```

versus

```
mysqldump args
```

If that's the case then if you don't specify an output file then the output will be to `stdout` (i.e. the terminal).

Comment: yes I did mysqldump args and expected file to be created :) instead I got it in terminal. I did > and it all went good.